# How to detect the strikeout text inside or under an <s> or <del> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

The issue occurs with the following text:

<s>**316.6.1 Structures**. Structures shall not be constructed</s>

Which is defined by the following HTML:

```html
<b>
    <s>
        <span style='font-size:10.0pt'>316.6.1 Structures</span>
    </s>
</b>
<s>
    <span style='font-size:10.0pt'>. Structures shall not be
        <span style='letter-spacing:.75pt'> </span>
        constructed
    </span>
</s>
```

But the `text-decoration` property is not returning the `line-through` value properly:

```
span_array = document.getElementsByTagName('span'));
> HTMLCollection(74812)

span_array[10648].innerText
> "316.6.1 Structures"
window.getComputedStyle(span_array[10648], null).getPropertyValue("text-decoration");
> "none solid rgb(0, 0, 0)"

span_array[10649].innerText
> ". Structures shall not be constructed"
window.getComputedStyle(span_array[10649], null).getPropertyValue("text-decoration");
> "none solid rgb(0, 0, 0)"
```

I would expect something like e.g.: `line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)`.
In short, what I need to achieve is somehow get a flag for the strikeout text above. FYI I should be able to run the script through Google Chrome Driver/Selenium.

Comment: are you able create and run functions? (I'm not familiar with Google Chrome Driver/Selenium)

Comment: `text-decoration` is propagated and accumulated on children, not inherited, so the result you are getting is correct. Which explains why, but otherwise isn't helpful. I don't know of any CSSOM property that allows direct access to the accumulation. `text-decoration` propagates into practically everything displayed except atomic inline boxes, and out of flow elements so you'd need to traverse the ancestors of the spans to the root, doing your own accumulation stopping only on an ancestor that is `display:inline-*`, `display:none`, `position:absolute/fixed` or  `float:left/right`.

Answer (score 1):

With this function you can get list of all styles for an element and it's ancestors, or simply check if a specific style is set:

```js
function getStyles(el, style = null, is = null, array = [])
{
  try
  {
    if (el)
    {
      const s = window.getComputedStyle(el);
      if (is !== null && style !== null && s[style] == is)
        return true;

      array[array.length] = style ? s[style] : s;
      return getStyles(el.parentNode, style, is, array);
    }
  }catch(e){}
  return is === null ? array : false;
}

// true/false if this element or it's parents have line-through text decoration
console.log( getStyles(document.querySelector("span"), "textDecorationLine", "line-through") ); 

//array of textDecorationLine values for the element and all parents
console.log( getStyles(document.querySelector("span"), "textDecorationLine") );

//list of all styles for the element and all parents
console.log( getStyles(document.querySelector("span")) );
```

```html
<b>
    <s>
        <span style='font-size:10.0pt'>316.6.1 Structures</span>
    </s>
</b>
<s>
    <span style='font-size:10.0pt'>. Structures shall not be
        <span style='letter-spacing:.75pt'> </span>
        constructed
    </span>
</s>
```